# Facing an error while executing the code illegal start of expression

Tags: java

QUESTION :-

Suppose a textile company “Grace Textile” human resource (HR) department. It has total 80
employees in 3 different branches. Employees are of 3 categories: Internees, Contract and Permanent
employees. Internees have internship of 6 months with fixed salary i.e, 20 thousand. Salaries are
calculated on basis of grades. Both contract and permanent employees have different pay scales.
Permanent employees also got benefits of pension and gratuity .Contract employees get monthly
salary and an annual additional bonus.
You are required to write a Java program comprising :
• Three Classes Employee, Contract Employee, Permanent Employee
• Employee class will have basic attributes of “Employee Id”, CNIC, Name, Grade, Salary and
Category (Internee, Contract, and Permanent). Use “I” for internee, “C” for “Contract” and
“P” for permanent
• CNIC will be of format 123-456-789
• Contract Employee class will have attributes/data members of Employee class and an
additional member “Bonus”
• Permanent Employee class will have attributes of Employee class along with 2 additional
attributes “Gratuity” and “Pension”
• Use proper data types for all data members
• Write display message of base class and derived classes which will print Emp Id of respective
class
• Write a function for Contract Employee Class that will calculate bonus. Roll number will be
stored in an array. Roll number will be your own vu id only digits (8 digits excluding first 2
characters). E.g, If your Roll number is BC12345678, 12345678 will be stored in array. Add
all 8 digits and name it “sum”. Calculate bonus with formula: (sum*1000)/2; Print value of
bonus.

Getting Error while executing the code :-

```
$javac HelloWorld.java
HelloWorld.java:80: error: illegal start of expression
pension = ;


     public class HelloWorld{

             public static void main(String []args){
                System.out.println("Hello World");
             }
        }


        public class Employee
        {
        private int id;
        private int cnic;
        private String name;
        private int grade;
        private int salary;
        private String categ;

        public Employee( int employeeId, int employeeCnic, String employeeName, int employeeGrade, int employeeSalary, String employeeCateg)
        {
        id = employeeId;
        cnic = employeeCnic;
        name = employeeName;
        grade = employeeGrade;
        salary = employeeSalary;
        categ = employeeCateg;

        }
        Employee()
        {
        System.out.println("Enter ID of the Employee:");
        id = get.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter CNIC of the Employee:");
        cnic = get.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Name of the Employee:");
        name = get.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Grade:");
        grade = get.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Salary of the Employee:");
        salary = get.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Category of the Employee (I, C, P):");
        categ = get.nextLine();
        }
        void display()
        {
        System.out.println("Employee ID: "+ id);
        System.out.println("Employee CNIC: "+ cnic);
        System.out.println("Employee Name: "+ name);
        System.out.println("Grade: "+ grade);
        System.out.println("Salary: "+ salary);
        System.out.println("Category: "+ categ);
        }
        class contractEmployee extends Employee
        {
        int bonus;
        contractEmployee()
        {
        System.out.println("Enter Grade: ");
        grade = get.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Salary:");
        salary = get.nextFloat();
        }
        void display()
        {
        System.out.println("=============================="+"\n"+"Full Time Employee Details"+"\n"+"=============================="+"\n");
        super.display();
        System.out.println("Salary: "+salary);
        System.out.println("Designation: "+ grade);
        }
        }
        class permanentEmployee extends Employee
        {
        int gratuatiy, pension;
        permanentEmployee()
        {
        System.out.println("Enter Number of Working Hours:");
        gratuatiy = get.nextInt();
        }
        void calculatepay()
        {
        pension = ;
        }

        void display()
        {
        System.out.println("=============================="+"\n"+"Part Time Employee Details"+"\n"+"=============================="+"\n");
        super.display();
        System.out.println("Number of Working Hours: "+pension);
        System.out.println("Salary for "+gratuatiy+" working hours is: $"+pension);
        }
        }

        class Employee
        {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
        System.out.println("================================"+"\n"+"Enter Full Time Employee Details"+"\n"+"================================"+"\n");
        permanentEmployee ob1 = new permanentEmployee();
        contractEmployee ob = new contractEmployee();
        System.out.println("================================"+"\n"+"Enter Part Time Employee Details"+"\n"+"================================"+"\n");
        ob1.display();
        ob.calculatepay();
        ob.display();
        }
        }

        }
```

Comment: Which line is line 80? Please Format your Code properbly. You miss a value in line pension=

Comment: You define the class `Employee` inside the class `Employee`?

Comment: The line `pension = ;` is wrong. That's the main problem the compiler is complaining (at this time). It's broken in many other ways too though.

Comment: @kayaman  What should i do now  ?

Comment: If you see why that line is wrong, you should fix it to be an actual assignment. If you *don't* see what the problem with that is, you should review a Java tutorial.

Comment: Rest of the code is fine ?

Comment: No, rest of the code is bad too. The compiler will complain about the rest of the code when you do something to fix the first issue. Of course that's a very inefficient way to program by writing a lot of broken code, finding out it doesn't even compile, and then try to make it work somehow.

Comment: @kayaman , Thanks !

Comment: didn't know stack overflow is a platform for doing the homework for people who don't like to read tutorials

Comment: @jimhawkins i read the tutorial first then i write the code , it's my starting dont have much experience in  java ! .

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem seems to be this part:

```
   void calculatepay() {
       pension = ;
   }
```

(As the compiler tells you)

*Other than that, we are not here, to solve your homework*

Comment: i neither asked for to do my homework i just stated my problem that i am facing !

Comment: I did not intend to be rude, i just wrote that sentence there, because my answer does not provide how to solve the problem. It just points out the line where the error is present.

Comment: The OP *doesn't* ask us to do the whole thing for us - just asks about a specific error, which is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: When did i said ? , To do for me . Just ask the simple query !

Comment: @khubaib: EJoshuaS just wanted to support you.

Comment: @zeropublix Majority of the comments  are not supportive , beside making futile statements . I just simply the ask the problem which i am facing , they started like that i am asking them to do my Assignment !